# Loop updating items in list

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have a function like this:

```
def main2():
    props = []
    prop_list = []
    i=0
    while (i < 10):
        new_prop = {
            'i': 1
        }
        props.append(new_prop)
        prop_list.append({'i': 1, 'props': props,})
        if i == 0:
            print prop_list
        i += 1
    print prop_list[0]
```

It outputs this:

```
[{'i': 1, 'props': [{'i': 1}]}]
{'i': 1, 'props': [{'i': 1}, {'i': 1}, {'i': 1}, {'i': 1}, {'i': 1}, {'i': 1}, {'i': 1}, {'i': 1}, {'i': 1}, {'i': 1}]}
```

Why is the final print not the same as the first print?  The previously added elements in the list appear to be updating when I append a new element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line,

```
prop_list.append({'i': 1, 'props': props,})
```

the dict includes the  `props` list object. This list is mutated on subsequent iterations through the loop:

```
props.append(new_prop)
```

The final value printed for `prop_list[0]` reflects this change.

---

Here is the same thing in isolation:

```
In [23]: x = []

In [24]: y = {'foo': x}

In [25]: y
Out[25]: {'foo': []}

In [26]: z = {'baz': x}

In [27]: x.append('bar')    # x is mutated

In [28]: y                 
Out[28]: {'foo': ['bar']}   # both y and z are affected

In [29]: z
Out[29]: {'baz': ['bar']}
```

---

If you do not want this to happen, make a copy of the list. To make a shallow copy of `props`, use `props[:]`:

```
prop_list.append({'i': 1, 'props': props[:]})
```

Note that the shallow copy, `props[:]` is *a new list* containing the exact same items as `props`. That means if `props` contained a mutable item such as a list, mutating that list would affect both `props` and its shallow copy.

To make a *deep* copy of all the items in `props` (recursively), use

```
import copy
prop_list.append({'i': 1, 'props': copy.deepcopy(props)})
```

Comment: The props list object will change, but why would prop_list.append update prop_list[0]?  shouldn't it just add prop_list[1], etc?

Comment: In Python variable names such as `props` "point" at objects. Each time through the loop, the variable name `props` is pointing to the very same object -- no copies of the object. Mutating that object affects *all* the places where that object exists.

Comment: @N.Taggart `prop_list[0]` holds a reference to the `props` object, so when that changes, it reflects in `prop_list[0]`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Since it's referencing the object and the object is changing... I get it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
prop_list.append({'i': 1, 'props': props,})
```

the `props` always refers to the same object, initialised at the top

```
props = []
```

and appended to in each iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: yes, the props object will iterate, but why would it update earlier list elements in prop_list?  in this case, should prop_list[0] be equal to prop_list[1]?

Comment: It should indeed. All elements of `prop_list` are equal.